# How to set noUiSlider with steps of 10 minutes?

Tags: jquery, nouislider

I have been working with application where I have integrated [noUiSlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/). I have already integrated it and working well with step of **15 minutes** for time based slider with range of 24 hours as below.

```
$(".time_range_slider").noUiSlider({
  start : [8, 18],
  behaviour : 'drag',
  connect : true,
  step : .25,
  range : {'min': 0, 'max': 24}
});

$(".time_range_slider").noUiSlider_pips({
  mode : 'steps',
  filter : filter_hour,
  stepped : true
});

function filter_hour(value, type) {
  return ((value * 100) % 100 == 0) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

But now i want to make step of **10 minutes**. I have tried many aspects like **step: .16** but not able to achieve expected result.

Please suggest any solution for same

Comment: Aint sure if this help or not but aint you missing the `()` on your `filter : filter_hour()<-` also you dont enter any value into the `filter_hour(Value missing)`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I have follwed this link https://refreshless.com/nouislider/pips/#section-steps

Comment: @Jeet check if my answer solve your problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My answer isn't using jquery case I don't know why noUiSlider isn't detected from jquery inside snippet, hope you can deal with that.

How is implemented:

- cosider 24 hours == 24h * 60 minutes ==> 1440 minutes
- use minutes range for selection:

  range : {'min': 0, 'max': 1440}
- format pipes labels and selector tooltips, using wNumb.js to show format hh:mm

snippet:

```js
var range = document.getElementById('time_range_slider');

range.style.height = '800px';
range.style.margin = '0 auto 30px';

var aproximateHour = function (mins)
{
//http://greweb.me/2013/01/be-careful-with-js-numbers/
 var minutes = Math.round(mins % 60);
  if (minutes == 60 || minutes == 0)
  {
    return mins / 60;
  }
  return Math.trunc (mins / 60) + minutes / 100;
}


noUiSlider.create(range, {
  start : [240, 1080],
  connect: true, 
  direction: 'rtl', 
  orientation: 'vertical', 
  behaviour: 'tap-drag', 
  step: 10,
  tooltips: true,
  range : {'min': 0, 'max': 1440},
  format:  wNumb({
  decimals: 2,
    mark: ":",
  encoder: function(a){
       return aproximateHour(a);
      }
 }),
  pips: {
    mode : 'steps',  
    format:  wNumb({
    mark: ":",
    decimals: 2,
  encoder: function(a ){
        return aproximateHour(a);
      }
  }),
   filter : filter_hour,
   stepped : true,
    density:1
  }
});



function filter_hour(value, type) {
  return (value % 60 == 0) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wnumb/1.0.4/wNumb.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/9.1.0/nouislider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/9.1.0/nouislider.js"></script>
<div id="time_range_slider"></div>
```